# DataGrid columns collection is not updating column widths programmatically or through grids properties

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

have searched all day for solution to vb.net web project, 3.5 framework (VS 2008) which uses DataGrid (not gridview) to set consistent widths for all 17 columns in my grid.  The grid is overflowing past the div area and the "Note" column particularly is very wide with very little text in it. For this particular column I've tried both allowing wrapping and nowrap and but the width never changes.  I've set the width of columns in the grid properties column collection with no change. Now I am setting the widths programmatically like so but with minimal effects.  The Note column is still quite wide.

Ideally what I would like is to fix column sizes (not auto grow or shrink) and have text that is too large to fit to be cut off.  I haven't designated an overall grid width.  Is that why the grid is misbehaving?

vb.net:

```
    DataGrid1.Columns(14).HeaderStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(25) 'LightDuty
    DataGrid1.Columns(14).HeaderStyle.Wrap = True
    '
    DataGrid1.Columns(15).HeaderStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(150) 'Note
    DataGrid1.Columns(15).HeaderStyle.Wrap = True
```

css:

```
 #grid
  {
   float:left;
   width:100%;
   /*border: 1px solid blue;*/
   margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
   padding:10px 10px 1px 10px;
   text-align:center;
  }
```

aspx: (just a portion of the top of the grid)

```
    <div id="grid">      
            <asp:datagrid  id="DataGrid1" runat="server"
                 Font-Names="Tahoma" 
                 Font-Size="Small" 
                 ShowFooter="True" 
                 DataMember="vwSomeDataSetTable"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                AllowSorting="True" 
                PageSize="25"
                 OnPageIndexChanged="DataGrid1_Paging"   >

                <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></FooterStyle>
                <SelectedItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Mode="NumericPages" 
                    Position="TopAndBottom" />
                <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#EBF5FF"></AlternatingItemStyle>
                <headerStyle Font-Bold="True"  ></headerStyle>

                <Columns>

                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="name" SortExpression="name" HeaderText="Employee">
                        <headerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" 
                            Font-Overline="False" Font-Size="Small" Font-Strikeout="False" 
                            Font-Underline="False" Wrap="False"> </headerStyle>
                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" 
                            Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" 
                            HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundColumn>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="LD" SortExpression="LD" 
                        HeaderText="LD">
                    <headerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" 
                            Font-Overline="False" Font-Size="Small" Font-Strikeout="False" 
                            Font-Underline="False" Wrap="False" />
                    <ItemStyle Font-Names="Webdings" Wrap="false" HorizontalAlign="Left" 
                            Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" 
                            Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False"/>
                    </asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Note" SortExpression="note" HeaderText="Note">
                        <headerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Bold="False" 
                            Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" 
                            Font-Underline="False" Wrap="False"></headerStyle>
                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" 
                            Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" 
                            HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundColumn>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naturally as soon as I ask for help, I come to a solution on my own!

UPDATE:  I removed everywhere I had set to allow wrapping in the grid columns collection properties for each headerstyle and itemstyle of every column as I realized some were set to wrap, some were not, creating inconsistencies with what I was attempting to set programmatically and once I did that, the columns started shrinking to a more usable size.  I still have a way to go, but it's getting better.

Comment: This morning the columns are wide again so I don't know what is causing them to be so randomly sized, especially when I am explicitly setting the widths.